# Keyboard stops responding after playing media

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, xfce

Sometimes, after playing some media (e.g. music from Spotify, a stream from Netflix) the keyboard stops responding, shortcuts and simple inputs don't work. Also the right click doesn't work, and the applications menu flickers when hovering over it. I'm running Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Xfce version 4.16. The laptop has Intel UHD Graphics 620, and the issue happens both when playing media on Firefox and on the linux Spotify player, so it is not limited to the browser.

When this happens, and it is more and more often, I need to open a virtual console with Ctrl + Alt + F1 and reboot from there. Is there a better way to fix this issue when it happens? Or is there a way to fix the root cause?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In case the non-answer disappears the question it asks is pertinent: *Do you use Chrome for playing media or does this happen with other media players?* Please [edit] your question to add details about the issue and also post hardware specifications. If you have Nvidia graphics I suspect you're using the default open-source driver when you probably should be using the proprietary drivers but let's not get ahead of ourselves. Please edit accordingly and we'll go from there, hopefully with a proper answer.

Comment: Edited the question, thank you

Comment: Thank you for editing. Now, the bad news: It's probably hardware failure.

Comment: @ChanganAuto that is indeed bad news. But if it is hardware failure, how come that a reboot from the virtual console fixes the issue? And what piece of hardware would be the one failing?

Comment: As so many other intermittent problems are solved, temporarily, by rebooting or shutting down. In this case the symptom suggests it may be due to overheating. But don't take my opinion just like that. You can ans should do some troubleshooting to rule out like booting a live session and using the computer the same way you feel triggers the problem. If the does the same then clearly hardware; if not then perhaps a reinstallation is in order.